# How can I manipulate a static URL using a function?

Tags: django

In my template file I have a classic use of:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'cat.png' %}">
```

Which as you'd expect spits out

```
<img src="STATIC_URL/cat.png">
```

Where the STATIC URL is set in settings.py

I want to be able to apply a function to this static URL, for example:

```
def url_change(input_url):
    output_url = input_url + '/somethingelse/'
    return output_url
```

So when I use `{% static 'cat.png' %}` it outputs the following:

```
STATIC_URL/cat.png/somethingelse/
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this anywhere but I would have thought it was quite easy, given that I already have a function defined.

Comment: Replace the `static` template tag by your own - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers nailed it! Thank you, I've got it working now.